# Random background color javascript setinterval

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my background one of three colors, but the code never works.  I think a syntax error is behind this, but I can't debug it. What's wrong?

```
var backcolor='yellow';
window.onload = function() 
var x=1;


setInterval(
function() {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = backcolor;
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
if (x==1)
    {backcolor='yellow';}
else if (x==2)
    {backcolor='orange';}
else if (x==3)
    {backcolor='red';}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You're missing the opening and closing brackets of window.onload = function. See http://jsfiddle.net/mcms7/1/.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `{` and `}` from your `onload` function. It should be:

```
var backcolor = 'yellow';
window.onload = function () {    
    var x = 1;

    setInterval(function () {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = backcolor;
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        if (x == 1) {
            backcolor = 'yellow';
        } else if (x == 2) {
            backcolor = 'orange';
        } else if (x == 3) {
            backcolor = 'red';
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Note that this sort of thing is much more obvious if you indent your code properly. Note also that you can move the `var backcolor` variable declaration inside your `onload` function with the `x` declaration - no need for it to be global.

Note also that you can make your function shorter and neater by getting rid of the if/else structure:

```
window.onload = function () {    
  var colors = ['yellow', 'orange', 'red'];

  setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor =
                          colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
  }, 1000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LscBA/2/